# xml to json converts all data types to string, is there a way to force the datatypes on elements(.net)

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, xslt

xml to json converts all data types to string, is there a way to force the datatypes on elements.

**my xml:**

```
<data>
<price>999</price>
<product>chapter</product>
</data>
```

**converts to:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "price": "999",
        "product": "chapter"
    }
}
```

**Desired: (force price to be integer)**

```
{
    "data": {
        "price": 999,
        "product": "chapter"
    }
}
```

Online tools also does the same, is there a way to force the datatypes ?

Comment: Is there a schema for the XML that declares the data types of the elements? And JSON doesn't have integers at all, it only has doubles for numbers.

Comment: Do you need a piece of code that produces the desired result or a tool?

Comment: What are you using to do the xml to json conversion?

Comment: The scenario I have is with .net webapi, response of which is an xml (transformed using an xslt), however some of the consumers consume it with response content type as application/json, and when they do that the datatypes of all the elements is converted to string. I am trying to see if I can embed something in the xml to force the datatypes(datetime, bool, double, number\integer) on the elements....I also tried the online tools like https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson, which does the same converts all the elements in xml as strings.

Comment: Can you generate the XML with some type annotation e.g. `<data xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><price xsi:type="xs:double">999</price>` and see whether that way your XML - JSON converted does output a JSON number and not  string?

Comment: didn't work..
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

**XML:**
                <DisplaySequenceNumber xsi:type="xsd:double">
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns15:Displaysequencenumber"/>
                </DisplaySequenceNumber>

**Output json:**

          "DisplaySequenceNumber": {
            "@xsi:type": "xsd:double",
            "#text": "10"
          },

Comment: @spodger, I am using the default .net web api, which converts to xml or json based on response content type. However I am seeing the same experience with online tools as well.. like codebeautify.org/xmltojson,

Comment: @ImantasSankalas, I am using .net web api, but I am trying to see even if any tool does it, if so how does it do